# For loop with multiThread ConsoleWriteLine

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine(i)).Start();
}
```

The output is

```
3
3
3
3
5
6
8
8
10
10
```

In my opinion, after the 10 times iterations, the maximum value of i should be 9.
I know the multiThread result in a incorrect output, but how does the maximum value act like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `for` loop, the maximum value of `i` is 9. The loop ends when when `i` is no longer smaller than 10, so after the loop `i` is 10.

Some of your threads were started before the loop finished, that's why you got the results from 3 to 8. Two threads were started after the loop finished, so you got 10 as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful about accidentally modifying captured variables like `i` after starting the thread, because the `i` is shared. So copy the `i` to local variable like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     var i1 = i;
     new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine(i1)).Start();
}
```

Read more about Closures here : [`The Beauty of Closures`](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) and [`Lambda expressions and captured variables.`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Passing_Data_to_a_Thread)

Answer (score 1):

It's called **Captured Variables** and it's exactly the problem [Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/) talk about [Here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Passing_Data_to_a_Thread).

**Here is his summary:**

> The problem is that the i variable refers to the same memory location
>   throughout the loop’s lifetime. Therefore, each thread calls
>   Console.Write on a variable whose value may change as it is running!
>
> The solution is to use a temporary variable as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  int temp = i;
  new Thread (() => Console.Write (temp)).Start();
}
```

> Variable temp is now local to each loop iteration. Therefore, each
>   thread captures a different memory location and there’s no problem.